# How do I display greetings according to my time zone using this python script?

Tags: python

I have tried several scripts to use my time zone but it didn't work. How can greeting adjust my time zone?

This is my python script:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
hour = now.hour
if hour < 4:
  waktu = "Selamat Dini Hari "
elif 4 <= hour < 12:
  waktu = "Selamat Pagi "
elif 12 <= hour < 15:
  waktu = "Selamat Siang ☀"
elif 15 <= hour < 17:<br/>
  waktu = "Selamat Sore ⛅"<br/>
elif 17 <= hour < 18:<br/>
  waktu = "Selamat Petang "<br/>
else:<br/>
  waktu = "Selamat Malam "<br/>

print("{}!".format(waktu))
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you know the time-zone of the person, who is calling the script somehow, then you can use that to something like this.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

local_tz = 'America/New_York' # this can be any timezone
_tz = pytz.timezone(local_tz) 
local_dtime = datetime.now(_tz)

hour = local_dtime.hour
if hour < 4:
  waktu = "Selamat Dini Hari "
elif 4 <= hour < 12:
  waktu = "Selamat Pagi "
elif 12 <= hour < 15:
  waktu = "Selamat Siang ☀"
elif 15 <= hour < 17:<br/>
  waktu = "Selamat Sore ⛅"<br/>
elif 17 <= hour < 18:<br/>
  waktu = "Selamat Petang "<br/>
else:<br/>
  waktu = "Selamat Malam "<br/>

print("{}!".format(waktu))
```